# How to Scan input data into multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a barcode which contains two input fields that I want to scan into two textbox fields in my wpf application. But when I scan, all input goes to first textbox which has focus.

If I scan input into Excel or notepad, its corrected scanned into different cells (or lines).

Here is what I have about my Textboxes:

```
<TextBox KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0"  x:Name="artTB" Height="30" />
<TextBox KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"  x:Name="snTB" Height="30" />
<TextBox KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"  x:Name="snplcTB" Height="30"  />
```

Comment: How are you "scanning"?

Comment: Can you please show us the code that's actually writing to textboxes? I believe your scanner is simply used as a keyboard device. So it basically writes to the currently focused element. And, for example, if you have a Notepad open and active, it will input everything there instead of your app. Right?

Comment: @RowlandShaw, what do u mean. Its just putting focus on first textbox, and then through device, I am scanning the barcode.

Comment: Yes @Somedust, thats correct. So actually there is not code for scanner, its acting as keyboard input device

Comment: Right, so you're scanning a barcode. What device are you using? What is its output?

Comment: '*Can you please show us the code that's actually writing to `TextBox`s?*'

Comment: @Sheridan, please see my comment above

Comment: @Sheridan There is none. Scanner simply acts as a keyboard. And inserts end of line chars after each lexeme entered.

Comment: @Irfan Does your scanner support other modes? I encountered exactly the same problem in the past with Honeywell handheld scanner. One solution was to switch the device to COM-mode and then listen to data coming from port.

Comment: @Irfan: Do you have two seperete bar-codes?

Comment: @Somedust, No it does not support other modes, and honestly, I dont want to be device dependent.

Comment: @Ramashankar, its just one barcode

Comment: @Irfan: ok, i think in that case you can just split the string in relevant part and place on different textbox.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you want your bar code split up, but you could try doing it in the [`TextBox.TextChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox focusedTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    string barCode = focusedTextBox.Text;
    TextBox1.Text = barCode.Substring(0, 3);
    TextBox2.Text = barCode.Substring(3, 3);
    TextBox3.Text = barCode.Substring(6, 3);
}
```

So the idea is to scan into one `TextBox` and just copy the relevant part of the scanned bar code to the relevant `TextBox`.

Comment: Thank you! +1 for giving me an idea... Because I have no idea how long can one field would be so can not use substring function that way. But I got the idea to have seperators between two different fields and then can split ..